# Finding the max area for a rectangle inside of a circle

Tags: geometry

I know how to find the max area, inside of a normal circle. This circle however is the inside of an aircraft and the floor must be there. How can this be done?

Here's a sketch of the inside of the aircraft: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJTas.png

The height is 3.57 meters and the diameter is 5.28 meters

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your question only to remove the 'differential geometry' tag because it has nothing to do with differential geometry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The diameter is $5.28$, so the radius is $r=2.64$. Let's also define $c=h-r=0.93$. Now we can write the equation for a circle of this radius centered at the origin: $x^2+y^2=r^2$. Our constrains on the rectangle are that it has $2$ points $(-a,b)$ and $(a,b)$ on the circle, and sits on the floor. By drawing a right triangle we have that this second constraint means

$$a\le \sqrt{r^2-c^2}\approx 2.471$$

We will check this second constraint when we are done.

Now we are ready to calculate the max area. The area of a rectangle which has a vertex at $(a,b)$ (where $a,b>0$) is $2a(b+c)$ (the base has length $2a$ and the height is $b+c$). We also have from our first constraint that $a^2+b^2=r^2$, so $b=\sqrt{r^2-a^2}$, and now we have a basic maximization problem - maximizing

$$A=2a\left(\sqrt{r^2-a^2}+c\right)$$

Taking the derivative with respect to $a$, we get
$$2\sqrt{r^2-a^2}-\frac{2a}{\sqrt{r^2-a^2}}+2c$$

Setting this to $0$ and solving we get ([via WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+-x%5E2%2Fsqrt%28r%5E2-x%5E2%29%2Bsqrt%28r%5E2-x%5E2%29%2Bc%3D0%2C+x%3E0%2C+r%3Ec%2C+c%3E0))

$$a=\frac{\sqrt{-c^2+\sqrt{c^4+8 c^2 r^2}+4 r^2}}{2\sqrt2}\approx 2.062$$

Notice that this value satisfies our second constraint.

Finally this gives us a maximum area of $A\approx 10.634$.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the figure below, you can see that the rectangle has a base of length $2r\cos\theta$ and a height of length $(h-r) + r\sin\theta$ so its area, as a function of $\theta$, is given by

$A(\theta) = 2r\cos\theta\,(h-r + r\sin\theta)$

so

$\displaystyle\frac{A(\theta)}{2rh} = a\,\sin\theta\cos\theta + (1-a)\,\cos\theta$

where $a \equiv \displaystyle\frac{r}{h}$. To maximise $A(\theta)$ we take the derivative with respect to $\theta$ and set it to zero, so the value of $\theta$ that maximises the area is the solution of the equation

$\displaystyle\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos(2\theta)} = \frac{a}{1-a}$.

$a$ is a known quantity so you can solve this numerically for $\theta$, from which you can get the width and height of the rectangle, as well as the maximum area.

**Edit:** Actually, since $\cos(2\theta) = 1 - 2\sin^2\theta$, the equation above reduces to a quadratic equation for $\sin\theta$, whose solution is

$\sin\theta = \displaystyle\frac{-1 + \sqrt{1+8b^2}}{4b}$

where $b \equiv \displaystyle\frac{a}{1-a}$.

[image]